# Update document after printing result

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to retrieve a list of documents, do something with the returned documents, then update the status to flag its been processed. This is what I have:

```
cursor = r.db("stuff").table("test").filter(r.row["subject"] == "books").run()
for document in cursor:
    print(document["subject"])
    document.update({"processed": True})
```

This seems to run OK but the "processed" field does not get updated as I would have expected. I'm probably approaching this incorrectly, so any pointers would be appreciated here.

UPDATE

This seems to work OK but I can't help thinking its somewhat inefficient:

```
cursor = r.db("stuff").table("test").filter(r.row["subject"] == "books").run()
for document in cursor:
    print(document["subject"])
    r.db("certs").table("test").get(document['id']).update({"tpp_processed": True}).run()
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using a `for_each`**

Instead of doing an `update` with a `run` every time you want to update a single document, you can saves the changes in an array and then use `forEach` to update all the documents in one query. This would look something like this:

```
cursor = r.table('30693613').filter(r.row["subject"] == "book").run(conn)
arr = list(cursor)
for row in arr:
    row['processed'] = True
r.expr(arr)
  .for_each(lambda row: r.table('30693613').get(row["id"]).update(row))
  .run(conn)
```

Instead of doing N networks calls for every update, this will only execute one network call.

**2. Building an update array and using `forEach`**

You can also do something similar in which you build an array and you just run one query at the end:

cursor = r.db("stuff").table("test").filter(r.row["subject"] == "books").run()
updated_rows = {}
for document in cursor:
    print(document["subject"])
    updated_rows.append({ id: document["id"], "tpp_processed": True }

// Afterwards...
r.expr(updated_rows)
      .for_each(lambda row: r.table('30693613').get(row["id"]).update(row))
      .run(conn)

**3. Using `no_reply`**

Finally, you can keep your query exactly the same as it is and then just `run` with `noreply`. That wait, your code will just keep running and won't wait till the database gets back a response.

```
cursor = r.db("stuff").table("test").filter(r.row["subject"] == "books").run()
for document in cursor:
    print(document["subject"])
    r.db("certs").table("test").get(document['id']).update({"tpp_processed": True}).run(conn, noreply=True)
```